# How to make a symmetry axis from the floor to my hero every time I click?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want my hero to do a symmetry axis from the floor. But when I click a second time, instead of returning above the floor, it continues to go down by axes of symmetry versus below it.

Here's the code:

```
func flip() {
    isUpsideDown = !isUpsideDown

    var scale: CGFloat!
    if isUpsideDown{
        scale = -1.0
    } else {
        scale = 1.0
    }
    let translate = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: scale*(size.height + kADGroundHeight), duration: 0.1)
    let flip = SKAction.scaleYTo(scale, duration: 0.1)
    runAction(translate)
    runAction(flip)
}
```

And by the way,

```
let kADGroundHeight: CGFloat = 20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that `size.height` isn't negative. After scaling to -1, it probably is. So your moveBy's y parameter is mis-calculated.

Comment: Have a look in the debugger at size.height, or log it via NSLog(). Let's see if it's negative when upside-down. If it goes negative, the math will have to be altered.